# Color not changing of Calendar Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am using CKCalendar for making calendar . I want to change color of date which is in my Array. I am using present Array

```
 present =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    int daysToAdd = 1;
    NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

    [present addObject:newDate1];
```

The value present Array is showing  "2015-09-03 07:37:30 +0000"

When i am apply the method for change the color.

```
- (void)calendar:(CKCalendarView *)calendar configureDateItem:(CKDateItem *)dateItem forDate:(NSDate *)date {
    // TODO: play with the coloring if we want to...

    NSLog(@"%@",date); // 2015-09-03 18:30:00 +0000

    NSLog(@"%@",present); //"2015-09-03 07:37:30 +0000"

    if ([present containsObject:date]) {
         dateItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

}
```

They show diffrent value so they not enter in my Code . Please Help . I am stuck .Any help would be apperciated.